# Handling API Rateimits In NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to think of a way to handle ratelimits, and i can't seem to figure it out, i try to use DiscordApp API they don't have a specific ratelimits instead they use something like X-RateLimit-Remaining X-RateLimit-Reset headers, how would i go with pausing the requests or something? I use superagent but i don't think that matters, any ideas appreciated, if you would like to see their ratelimit rules https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/blob/master/docs/topics/Rate_Limits.md this explains it in a short time.

Comment: Can you show what you've got? When are you performing the requests, when a user interacts, or you're just polling the discord API? Depending on what you're doing the answer will be slightly different.

Comment: Well to use the rest api for example send msg etc all endpoints do have a ratelimit

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the response headers and evaluate the following:

- X-RateLimit-Global - Returned only on a HTTP 429 response if the rate limit headers returned are of the global rate limit (not per-route)
- X-RateLimit-Limit - The number of requests that can be made
- X-RateLimit-Remaining - The number of remaining requests that can be made
- X-RateLimit-Reset - Epoch time (seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970) at which the rate limit resets

For example, if `X-RateLimit-Remaining` is 1, you can make another call to that API and on the remaining header becomes 0. Then, you need to check `X-RateLimit-Reset` that gives you the timestamp at which you can again access the APIs. You can set up a `setTimeout` by getting the difference between the current time and the reset time, so you can continue from then.

Comment: Thanks but setTimeout may not be best idea, as i may be doing lots of requests such as sending messages is often used, most people i think use a ratelimit bucket queue to do this, but i have no idea how to do make something like it.

Comment: In that case, most likely you can use the `queue` control flow from the `async` library. It helps you have queues with different concurrency levels and callbacks for notification. It's worth looking into https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue